# python install dependencies to project

Tags: python, pip

I want to make an application for Sailfish OS using QML and Python. I want to have models in python and save data to sqlite using SQLAlchemy. Problem is I have no idea how can I get dependencies to my project and Sailfish OS does not have SQLAlchemy in repository. I tryed to install it using pip to lib directory in my project using

`pip install --install-option="--install-purelib=pwd/lib" sqlalchemy`

It installed SQLAlechemy as i expected, but when i tryed to run my project, it crashed on select with where condition - but the same code worked fine when I imported SQLAlchemy from my system.

I both installed SQLAlchemy are 1.0.8 version.

Select, which works with my SQLAlchemy installed without prefix

`def getValue(self, key):
        s = select([self.table.c.value]).where(self.table.c.key==key)
        return self.con.execute(s).fetchone()`

and error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/home/tobik/Buhvico/Programovani/beardware/hgclient/qml/hgo/models.py", line 58, in getValue
    s = select([self.table.c.value]).where(self.table.c.key==key)
  File "", line 2, in where
  File "/home/tobik/Buhvico/Programovani/beardware/hgclient/qml/hgo/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/base.py", line 45, in _generative
    fn(self, *args[1:], **kw)
  File "/home/tobik/Buhvico/Programovani/beardware/hgclient/qml/hgo/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 2897, in where
    self.append_whereclause(whereclause)
  File "/home/tobik/Buhvico/Programovani/beardware/hgclient/qml/hgo/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 3122, in append_whereclause
    True_._ifnone(self.whereclause), whereclause)
  File "/home/tobik/Buhvico/Programovani/beardware/hgclient/qml/hgo/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 1929, in and
    return cls.construct(operators.and, True_, False_, *clauses)
  File "/home/tobik/Buhvico/Programovani/beardware/hgclient/qml/hgo/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 1863, in _construct
    util.coerce_generator_arg(clauses)
  File "/home/tobik/Buhvico/Programovani/beardware/hgclient/qml/hgo/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 1862, in 
    for clause in
  File "/home/tobik/Buhvico/Programovani/beardware/hgclient/qml/hgo/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 3766, in _expression_literal_as_text
    return _literal_as_text(element, warn=True)
  File "/home/tobik/Buhvico/Programovani/beardware/hgclient/qml/hgo/lib/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 3787, in _literal_as_text
    "instead" % type(element)
hgo.lib.sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: SQL expression object or string expected, got object of type  instead`

Thanks for ur suggestions :)